# Why are bikes on bus?

Tags: silicon-valley

In the series [Silicon Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Valley_(TV_series)), Season 2 Episode 10, When Richard is contacting the guy at home, why is the bus having bicycles attached to the front?

[image: Bike on bus]

Comment: Does it have a meaning to the plot? As far as I can see it's simply a public bus transporting some bikes of the passengers.

Comment: is this a normal bus?

Comment: [Yes, some transit authorities just have buses with bike racks, is all.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_carrier#United_States) AFAIK, this has nothing to do with the show.

Comment: [(See here)](http://www.anthonynachor.com/uploads/3/4/6/6/3466466/225540188_orig.jpg)

Comment: [...well, 'nothing to do with the show' except maintaining authenticity.]

Comment: I live in the Silicon Valley area and can confirm Walt's comment that this is part of maintaining authenticity. Almost all forms of mass transit around here have some way for people to carry their bicycles: buses will have racks like in the picture or allow bikes to be brought on board; [BART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_Area_Rapid_Transit) trains have two open areas with bike racks near the doors on each car; and [Caltrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caltrain) trains have two whole cars per train where the entire lower level is bike racks, with seats on the upper level

Comment: I have never been to silicon Valley, I had no idea about this. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cities if not all, a great number of buses have bike racks for two bikes. Your clip showing a bus with two bikes on it is simply a way in keeping with maintaining authenticity as Wait has pointed out in his comment. Where I live, bikes on buses are very commonplace.

Even here in Canada, bike rakes on buses are very popular:

> Many of the following routes are in and around the City of Vancouver. Vancouver has an extensive public transport system run by "Translink." most buses have bike racks for two bikes and there are three major "Skytrain" routes which will carry bikes. - [Routes, Paths & Directions](http://www.adamk.ca/local_routes.html)

We even have a [Tunnel Shuttle Trailer](http://www.adamk.ca/local_routes.html) for bikes.

[image: Tunnel Shuttle Trailer]

The website [Go Bike by Bus](http://www.gotransit.com/public/en/docs/publications/GO_Bike_By_Bus.pdf) shows how to load your bike onto a bus.